# Escape variables containing spaces and special characters in GNU parallel

Tags: zsh, gnu-parallel

I try to parallelize the optimization of a PDF file. (I’m on a Mac)

```
#!/bin/zsh

TMP_DIR=$(mktemp -d)
DOCUMENT="/some/path/with/sp aces/and/üö chars.pdf"

mkdir "$DOCUMENT"_split

#split pdf into single pages
/usr/local/bin/pdfseparate "$DOCUMENT" "$TMP_DIR/${$(basename $DOCUMENT)%.pdf}_%d.pdf"

find "$TMP_DIR" -mindepth 1 -maxdepth 1 -name "*.pdf" ! -print0 | parallel -0 -j+0 '/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf {} {.}_optimized.pdf && mv {.}_optimized.pdf $DOCUMENT_split/$(basename {});'
```

Everything works fine, as long as there are no spaces or special characters in the path. The `mv`command fails:

```
usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory
```

I tried the following which helps the directory path, but wrapping `$(basename {})` the same way doesn’t work.

```
mv {.}_optimized.pdf '\"$DOCUMENT\"'_split/$(basename {})
```

Comment: You are passing the argument to `parallel` within single quotes, which means that `$DOCUMENT` does not get expanded. BTW, I don't know how parallel is supposed to work, but I would also verify which shell is used to run the parallel command.

Comment: If I pass it like so `'… mv {.}_optimized.pdf '\"$DOCUMENT\"'_split/$(basename {})'` it works for `$DOCUMENT` but for `$(basename {})` it does not.

Comment: Of course not, because now you have `$(basename)` within single quotes  :-DDDDD

Comment: Even like this, it doesn’t work. `'… mv {.}_optimized.pdf '\"$DOCUMENT\"'_split/'\"$(basename {})\"`

Comment: Don't forget that you are building a string together which _parallel_ is processed further. Most likely, _parallel_ itself also needs suitable quotes around the parts of the string. I would first test what string is produced here, and then supply the missing quotes.

Comment: It just occured to me, that `$(basename)` must be passed to _parallel_ for expansion, and not expanded by the calling shell. Therefore perhaps something like `parallel .... " ps2pdf {} '"$DOCUMENT"'.......split/\"$(basename {})\""`

Comment: Just as a debugging aid: I always have at hand a small zsh script `echo_pars`, with simply does a `for arg; do printf "###%s###\n" $arg; done` and thereby shows me the arguments it actually gets (including spaces), and when I try to fix something which needs complicated quoting to be passed, as in your case, I would temporarily replace the command I really want to executed, by my `echo_pars`. This makes it easier to debug quoting problems.

Answer (score 1):

GNU Parallel's replacement strings will quote the resulting string correctly. This means that it is safe to use on even crazy file names:

```
touch "  Spacey  My brother's 12\" records.txt"
find . -print0 | parallel -0 echo {} {.}
```

This guarantee does not apply to variables and especially not to output from commands executed in the command template.

```
# This does not do what you expect
DOCUMENT="It's  \"two\"  spaces"
find . -print0 | parallel -0 echo $DOCUMENT $(basename {})
```

Instead of `basename` you can use the replacement string {.}. `$DOCUMENT` is harder to get right every time:

```
DOCUMENT="It's  \"two\"  spaces"
export DOCUMENT
find . -print0 | parallel -0 echo '"$DOCUMENT"' {.}
```

Often it is easier just to make a bash function and call that:

```
doit() {
  f="$1"
  echo "$DOCUMENT" "$(basename "$f")"
}
export -f doit
export DOCUMENT
find . -print0 | parallel -0 doit
```

(PS: `-j+0` has been default for years).

Answer (score 0):

It just occured to me that there is a much easier possibility than fiddling around with all that quoting: If you make `DOCUMENT` an environment variable, you can let do **all** the expansion by the shell invoked by `parallel`:

```
export DOCUMENT
```

Only since I don't know what shell *parallel* is using, I would not rely on the hope that it runs zsh, and would prepare the argument so that it would work even in a POSIX shell:

```
... parallel -0 -j+0 '/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf {} {.}_optimized.pdf && mv {.}_optimized.pdf "$DOCUMENT_split/$(basename "{}")";'
```

In this way, the shell executed by *parallel* sees exactly what is in between the two single quotes. This means that you even can test that approach by substituting suitable values for DOCUMENT and {}.

Comment: This almost works, when I wrap `$DOCUMENT` in extra double quotes but it unfortunately appends an `'` to the filename. I tested it like so: `parallel -0 -j+0 'echo $(basename "{}");'`

Comment: This works: `parallel -0 -j+0 '/usr/local/bin/ps2pdf {} {.}_optimized.pdf && mv {.}_optimized.pdf ""$DOCUMENT"_split/$(basename {})";'`